# async calls in mvc view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asynchronous

I have the requirement to call an asynchronous method from within a view but I have no idea how to go about this.
My view looks like this:

```
@using Skipstone.Web.Services;

@{
    var service = new UserService(new CompanyService());
    var users = await service.GetAll();

    ViewBag.Title = "Manage Users";
}

@section Breadcrumb {
    <ol class="breadcrumb">
        <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="/Manage/Users">Users</a></li>
    </ol>
}

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="message"></div>

            <a href="/Manage/Users/Create">Create a new user</a>

            <table class="table table-bordered users sortable">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th data-defaultsort="desc">Username</th>
                        <th>Email</th>
                        <th>Status</th>
                        <th data-defaultsort="disabled">Member of</th>
                        <th data-defaultsort="disabled"></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    @foreach (var user in users)
                    {
                        <tr id="@user.Id">
                            <td>@user.UserName</td>
                            <td>@user.Email</td>
                            <td>
                                @if (user.IsApproved)
                                {
                                    <span class="label label-success label-approved">Approved</span>
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    <span class="label label-warning label-approved">Rejected</span>
                                }

                                @if (user.IsLockedOut)
                                {
                                    <span class="label label-danger label-locked">Locked</span>
                                }
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @foreach (var group in user.MemberOf)
                                {
                                    <text>@group </text>
                                }
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @if (user.IsApproved)
                                {
                                    <a href="#" data-id="@user.Id" class="btn btn-default reject"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-sign"></span> @*<div class="visible-md visible-lg">Reject</div>*@</a>
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    <a href="#" data-id="@user.Id" class="btn btn-default approve"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok-sign"></span> @*<div class="visible-md visible-lg">Approve</div>*@</a>
                                }
                                <a href="/Manage/Users/Edit/@user.Id" class="btn btn-default"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span> @*<div class="visible-md visible-lg">Edit</div>*@</a>
                                <a href="#" data-id="@user.Id" class="btn btn-default delete"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span> @*<div class="visible-md visible-lg">Delete</div>*@</a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    }
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/bootstrap-sortable.css")" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/bootstrap-sortable.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.skipstone-users-index.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
}
```

as you can see, the line that states:

> var users = await service.GetAll();

is an asynchronous method, but you can't call asynchronous methods without putting them into a async method so I have a vicious circle going on.

Has someone come across this before?
Is there something I can do to make it work.

**NB: I do not have access to the controller, because this is a virtual view and does not have a controller, it is served from the database**

Cheers,

/r3plica

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, what do you mean by 'virtual view without controller served from the database'?

Comment: I mean there is no controller. I use a custom VirtualPathProvider and MvcRouteHandler to route any traffic that is virtual. This then matches the path with a path store in my database which then serves up the html for the required View. So, because of this there is no controller, just the View which is served up dynamically

Comment: similar to http://www.umbraworks.net/bl0g/rebuildall/2009/11/17/ASP_NET_MVC_and_virtual_views

Comment: @r3plica Are you able to add a controller?

Comment: Not really, because I allow users to created/edit and delete their own pages.

Comment: @r3plica Ok - I suggest calling the service using ajax if thats possible. Make the call once the view/page has loaded. However this would also using juery/javascript to display the results (usernames)

Comment: You can easily use a controller and have create this as a partial view to call the certain ActionMethod when it needs to update.

Comment: @r3plica: Sorry, you can't use `await` in Razor syntax. There's a possibility it may be done in the future; open a UserVoice suggestion to bring it to Microsoft's attention. In the meantime, you'll have to use a controller or *something* like that.

Comment: @heymega good idea, I think that is the solution.

Answer (score 0):

This is bad approach to use async calls in ASP.NET because ASP.NET page is async by itself and won't wait until your async operations will be finished. But there are some tricks - read Scott Hanselman's post [here](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/TheMagicOfUsingAsynchronousMethodsInASPNET45PlusAnImportantGotcha.aspx) If no other options exist I would suggest to run it synchronously by calling RunSynchronously()